# Unable to detect the String encoding

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8

Can you find out what encoding is used in the string below? It's supposed to be the word resume, with an accented e. I tried setting the encoding to latin-1 in vi (default being utf-8), but still couldn't read it.

```
72 ef bf bd 73 75 6d ef bf bd

|r...sum...|
```

Comment: The person to ask which encoding the author used is the author. Encodings are not divined, they are communicated—possbily by standard, specification or convention in a certain context. A very common way when communicating via HTTP is the Content-Type response header.

Answer (score 4):

Your hexadecimal data is the UTF-8 encoding of the string `r�sume�`, where `ef bf bd` is the encoding of the *replacement character*, usually shown as the question mark on black background.

So your string has already been corrupted. At one point it probably was `résumé`. But then it was saved in an encoding without the accented e, and they were replaced with the *replacement character*.

Answer (score 2):

EF BF BD is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode Replacement character U+FFFD �.

That means that this will never spell ré­su­mé, no matter how you decode it.

Somewhere along the line something already messed up the decoding (presumably by decoding a `byte[]` using the wrong decoding).